# How can I easily switch between development and live configurations when archiving for deployment?

Tags: xcode, deployment, configuration

What is the best way to have multiple configurations (dev/testing/live/etc.) for an iPad app and easily switch between them when archiving for deployment?

A common example would be to switch from the testing version of a web service URL, https://testing.mycompany.com/api, to a live version, https://customer.server.com/api.

I think it's a safe assumption that live config would never be used when developing in XCode, but it's very possible that some deployments to iPads would want to use a testing config while others obviously have live configs.

Comment: @Jacques I do not agree with these tag edits. I could just as easily be using Jetbrains as my editor and I'd still need a best practice way to have multiple runtime configurations for an iOS app. Just as in .NET I'd use a web.config or app.config regardless of whether I was using Visual Studio or not.

Comment: You're free to remove the [xcode] tag if you don't think it applies, but of the three that I removed, only [ios] even comes close to being relevant. [ipad] is only for questions which are _specific_ to that one device, and [objective-c] is for questions which either contain some ObjC code and/or are about the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different schemes, for which of your needs. There you can define what kind of build you want to make.

Comment: Where in a scheme does one store configuration values such a web service locations?

Comment: try the following, it helped me before: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/06/20/managing-ios-configurations-per-environment-in-xcode-4/